# Why do I get error (404) in my Next.js POST method?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD using next js. For now I'm just try to create a simple POST method that inputs the email , name and password, but I'm having a problem and getting an error.

I don't know why I get this error

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/create-users 404 (Not Found)

This is my directory.

[image]

This is my app/users/page.tsx

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Users = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await fetch("/api/create-user", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });

      setFormData({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, "error from client");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Here is a List of our Users</h1>
      <form
        className="flex flex-col gap-2 items-center justify-center"
        action=""
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        <input
          className="border-2 border-zinc-700 px-4 py-2"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formData.name}
          placeholder="name"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <input
          className="border-2 border-zinc-700 px-4 py-2"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={formData.email}
          placeholder="email"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <input
          className="border-2 border-zinc-700 px-4 py-2"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={onChange}
        />

        <button
          type="submit"
          className="border-2 border-zinc-700 px-4 py-2 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-500/90"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

And this is my app/api/create-user.ts

// app/api/create-users.ts

```
import { db } from "@/lib/prisma";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
      const user = await db.user.create({
        data: {
          name,
          email,
          password,
        },
      });

      res.status(201).json(user); // Respond with a 201 status code for resource creation
    } catch (error:any) {
      res.status(500).json(error);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).end(); // Method Not Allowed if not a POST request
  }
}
```

This is my schema.prisma

```
model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String   @unique
  name      String?
  password  String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

}
```

prisma.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
};

export const db = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = db;
```

Comment: Is ```create-user.ts``` supposed to be ```create-users.ts```?

Comment: @ewokx, it still doesn't work, I tried changing it.

Comment: After the change, what error is showing?

Comment: @Stykgwar
You ignore naming rules in nextjs api router. You need to name it `route.ts` instead of `create-user.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Your api needs to have a folder that then has a route.tsx file inside of it.

Look into routr handlers on the next docs for app router

Answer (score 0):

The `/api` directory is outdated and replaced with `app/[api-route]/route.tsx`.

So your folder structure should look like this:

```
/app
--/api // if you wanna keep the 'api' path
----/create-user // but it's best to rename it to 'user' since verbs should be avoided for API endpoints
------/route.tsx
```

`route.tsx` is where you write your handlers.
But the name of your handlers should match the verb they handle.
So for your POST /create-user, the handler function name should be `POST`.

You can see it in action here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/clever-joana-xmwvzf?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n7000c3b6hvdc9mane%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600033b6hadjzmiq6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600093b6h3uwxn7ua%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n6000b3b6herdhm8p2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B63.77265238879736%252C36.22734761120264%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clomc06n600033b6hadjzmiq6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600033b6hadjzmiq6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600023b6hfn5zpo6b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fusers%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc2d8a00hi3b6hqffb9szn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Flayout.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc4e8l00u93b6hhl7z3m2g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fapi%252Fcreate-user%252Froute.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomcbz5j02h13b6hliosl9wx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clomcbz5j02h13b6hliosl9wx%2522%257D%252C%2522clomc06n6000b3b6herdhm8p2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n6000a3b6h837yx3cy%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fusers%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n6000b3b6herdhm8p2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clomc06n6000a3b6h837yx3cy%2522%257D%252C%2522clomc06n600093b6h3uwxn7ua%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600043b6hkfibrffb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600053b6h5u4rxqnj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600063b6h3aetqxqf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600073b6hwqebzd9i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522lint%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600083b6hib7vih63%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522install%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600093b6h3uwxn7ua%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clomc06n600043b6hkfibrffb%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Notice that I removed `res: NextAPIResponse` and replaced `res.status().json()` with `return NextResponse.json(user, { status: 201 })`;

This is based on the latest Next docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json